Can't power RP4 from same active hub the peripherals are connected to
I'm building something NAS-like with a RPI4 Model B Rev 1.2 and 2 hard disks. I'm using an active hub for the hard disks and wanted to power the RPI4 from it as well. Here is how I wanted to wire it:

The active hub (EXSYS EX11295HMS) has 4 normal ports. To simplify the drawing, only 3 are shown. The Pi is powered from port 3. Disk1 and disk 2 are attached via port 1 and 2 respectively. One of data usb ports on the pi is hooked up to the host port of the hub.
If I start by connecting P3 to the pi to give the pi power, the pi boots correctly and I can SSH into it. As soon as I plug in the HP-Pi connection, the pi goes down and seems to be stuck rebooting or something. It still blinks but I can't access it anymore. If I'm logged in at the time, the connection drops. It doesn't matter whether the disks are attached or not.
What seems to work is to power the PI from a separate power supply instead of the P3-PI connection and then plug in the HP-Pi connection. But this requires two separate power lines, which I hoped to avoid. The active hub itself should provide enough power: 2.5A per port, max total power 27W. The Pi4 specs request 3A, but 1.2A seem to be set aside for powering peripherals, which is the job of the hub anyway.
Two questions:

Should what I have done work in principle? If not, why?
If it should work in principle, any ideas why it doesn't in my case?

Thank you

It is unclear whether the hub would ever power a Pi. Does it work without other connections? No one knows what the hub actually does (and most have no specification).  There is no need to have multiple power connections to the Pi.

@Milliways Sorry, not sure I completely get it. As I wrote, the hub does power the pi fine by connecting port 3 to the power of the pi. But I still need the data connection, so I need to plug in pi in the host port as well. As soon as I plug in the data connection, the system goes down.

This would seem to be a problem with the hub. The Pi USB (like all USB hosts) supplies power. This should be negotiable but the Pi USB has no negotiation or power control (except a hardware limit on total current). You might have some success if you use a custom cable without a 5V connection.

@Milliways Ah, right, thank you!

Yes, you can do this. See here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/power-rpi-from-same-powered-usb-hub-as-its-peripherals I have done it myself.

@LiamProven Thanks! Good to know that it can be done in principle.
